# Issue with 2sxc remove action

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

I have just started a new site where I am using 2sxc version 11.11.4 (started with 11.7.3 and upgraded to see if that would fix it). I have the data and views set up just like I have done on another site using version 10.25.2. On the newer version though, I'm unable to use the remove button/action. I did some searching and found a few references to adding lines to the web config file (https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1654, https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2205). I tried this and it worked great.

So, my question: will a fix be implemented for this or will we have to add these lines of code to the web config file on any site we use 2sxc on?

Also, could these lines of code affect any other DNN features, other modules, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about my solution here
https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2205#issuecomment-705647892

This is specific to a server where the WebDAV features have been added/enabled in Windows. I do not think its an issue that can or will be fixed in 2sxc.

I do know that it is safe to add those two  items in web.config. All its doing is telling ASP.NET to NOT make WebDAV available in this application's (DNN's) context. I am not aware of any DNN feature or modules that need or use WebDAV. Its just something handed down from the server because its installed and its causing a weird change in behavior that makes the DELETE (and other) command types get ignored (IMHO, presumably because they are handled before they get to DNN).

Comment: Jeremy is right - it's actually an IIS misconfiguration issue.

Comment: Okay, thanks! As long as it's not going to cause other issues, we can just stick with making those changes.

Comment: psst, don't forget to accept my answer :)